# Obtain null space or single dimensional space which is its best approximation efficiently

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, eigenvector, svd

I have been doing this using an svd computation

```
[U, S, V] = svd(A)
```

wherein I use the last column of A as my null space approximation. Since A gets really large, I realized that this is slowing down my computation.

For null(A), the documentation seems to suggest that it does an SVD anyways. Also, it does not work if A is full rank. An SVD proceeds by finding the largest singular value, then the next one and so on whereas I just need the smallest one.

This seems to be a big bottleneck. Will really appreciate help on this.
Am using MATLAB.

Thanks.

Comment: Where does matrix A come from, and what is the purpose of your calculation? Why is the smallest eigenvalue so important? One usually wants the largest few (e.g. in PCA).

Comment: A is a 4xN matrix. It contains the homogenous coordinates of N points. I basically need a solution to Ax = 0. (Basically, I need the closest fitting plane to those points.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all points are from a plane, call SVD with just a sample.

Comment: Taking a sample is what I think I'll end up doing now but I think there is a way to get the smallest singular value vector by using A to construct a matrix.

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28matrix%29#Numerical_computation_of_null_space) Wikipedia article describes three methods for the numerical computation of the null space: reduction (Gaussian elimination), [SVD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/svd-singular-value-decomposition.html), and [QR decomposition](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/qr.html). In brief, (1) reduction is "not suitable for a practical computation of the null space because of numerical accuracy problems in the presence of rounding errors", (2) SVD is the "state-of-the art approach", but it "generally costs about the same as several matrix-matrix multiplications with matrices of the same size", and (3) the numerical stability and the cost of QR decomposition are "between those of the SVD and the reduction approaches".

So if SVD is too slow, you could give a chance to [QR decomposition](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/qr.html). The algorithm with your notations is as follows: "`A` is a `4xN` matrix with `4<N`. Using the QR factorization of `A'`, we can find a matrix such that `A'*P = Q*R = [Q1 Q2]*R`, where where `P` is a permutation matrix, `Q` is `NxN` and `R` is `Nx4`. Matrix `Q1` is Nx4 and consists of the first 4 columns of `Q`. Matrix `Q2` is `Nx(N-4)` and is made up of the last `N-4` columns of `Q`. Since `A*Q2 = 0`, the columns of `Q2` span the null space of `A`."

Matlab implementation: `[Q, R, P] = qr(A', 'matrix');` The columns of matrix `Q2 = Q(:, 5:end);` give the null space of `A`.

Comment: Makes sense.. Although, isn't there a way to get create another matrix using A in which the singular values would be reversed? I could just call svds after that and get only the first or the second columns... That could be faster than this. Anyways, I just sampled coz N was too large anyways. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

This answers builds on your comment that what you actually want to do is to solve `Ax = 0`. For this purpose, a complete nullspace computation is usually inefficient. If you want a least-squares approximation to `x`, have a look into the matlab operator `\` (see `help mldivide`).

In other cases, an "economic" SVD via `svd(A,0)` might be helpful for non-square matrices (it does not compute the full S, but only the non-zero block).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `A\zeros` will return `zeros`.

Comment: True, because it's the solution of smallest norm to `A x = 0`.